# How to check if a flow running user is a Partner?

Tags: visual-workflow, partner-communities

I am trying to check in a flow if the running user is a Partner Community member.

I am using this:

[image]

But even when using a partner user in the 'Debug Runas', I get wrong data:

[image]

I tried to use the 'User' object, instead of the 'Profile' - same results:

[image]

same result:

[image]

The user type on the user record is "Partner"

[[image]]

Where is my mistake ?

How can I check if a running flow user is a partner community member ?

- Checkgin using SOQL: I get correct data:
  SELECT Id, Name, IsActive, Profile.Name FROM User WHERE ProfileId IN ( SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE UserType = 'PowerPartner' )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please look at this Example:

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/de/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A8ct9SAB

I think this should solve your Problem.

Comment: Thanks, don't know how I didn't think of it on my own ^^